# Sorting list of string elements in a custom sorting order

Tags: java, sorting

I have a use case where I need to sort a list of strings in a custom sorting order.
Consider input list as - ["segment", "sub_category", "category", "segment"], after sorting sortedList should be - ["category", "sub_category", "segment", "segment"].

I have sorted this as below:

```
Map<String, Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
orderMap.put("category", 1);
orderMap.put("sub_category", 2);
orderMap.put("segment", 3);

Comparator comp = new Comparator() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        orderMap.get(s1) - orderMap.get(s2);
    }
}
```

The above code does return the list in my custom sorted order which is - ["category", "sub_category", "segment", "segment"].

However, I'm just concerned about whether this is the best approach in terms of space and time complexity or whether there is a better and easier way to achieve custom sorting.

Could someone please help and guide me?

Comment: found a simpler way instead of creating a Comparator as below: `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(orderMap::get));`

Answer (score 1):

The [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library has the [`Ordering.explicit`](https://guava.dev/releases/33.0.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit(T,T...)) methods which can be used to create a `Comparator` over a fixed known set of values with a defined ordering among them.  That is exactly the use case described here.

```java
Comparator<String> comp = Ordering.fixed("category", "sub_category", "segment");
```

Comment: Thanks, M. Justin!! let me give it a try. I hope this won't increase the time and space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I will define an enum like

```
enum SortKey {
  CATEGORY,
  SUB_CATEGORY,
  SEGMENT
}
```

Note how the values are declared in the desired sort order. Then I write a method that maps my strings to the sort key.

```
private static SortKey valueOfMyString(String myString) {
  return switch(myString) {
    case "category" -> CATEGORY;
    case "sub_category" -> SUB_CATEGORY;
    case "segment" -> SEGMENT;
    default -> throw new AssertionError(myString);
  };
}
```

And finally define a comparator with

```
Comparator.comparing(s -> valueOfMyString(s));
```

[Here is a real life example](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:android/src/com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/NameComparator.java;drc=a6e6fa8c55c47a61d3badf213c066b792e1c78a9)

Comment: Thanks, Juan C Nuno for your response, let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The space and time complexity of your solution are fine.  [`HashMap.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) operates in constant time, so the overall operation operates in constant time.  Storing the elements in a `HashMap` should be efficient in terms of space.